# How to creat object from kotlin class in java class?

Tags: java, android, class, object, kotlin

I created a kotlin class of a car and I want to creat object from this class in a java class ?? How could I do that ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Answer (score 2):

A class created in Kotlin can be instantiated the same way a class created in Java is.

Example:

```
// Kotlin
data class Car(val name: String, val yearProduced: Int)


// Java
Car car = new Car("Ford", 2017);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do like

   lateinit var myObj: MyClass

in function you can do like

```
{    
 myObj=MyClass()
}
```

2. val myObj= MyClass()

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Kotlin Class For Example:

open class Foo{

```
open fun testFooFuncation(): Foo? {

    println("Call Kotlin Foo Class form Java Class...")

    return Foo()
}
```

}

2. call from java class for example:

public class CarClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args){



    Foo foo = new Foo();
    System.out.print(foo.testFooFuncation());


}
```

}